# Possible to access Piwik getVisitorLog through HTTP API?

Tags: matomo

I'm building some reporting tool. Ideally I want to avoid going through web server logs myself and use (some of) the power of Piwik.

The stuff I get from the visitor log would be a good start, this is at http://example.com/piwik/index.php?module=CoreHome&action=index&idSite=1&period=day&date=yesterday#/module=Live&action=getVisitorLog&idSite=1&period=day&date=yesterday

Unfortunately I can't find a `getVisitorLog` action in the HTTP API docs at
http://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/reporting-api#Actions (and it's also not an undocumented feature, `method=Actions.getVisitorLog` gives me

> The method 'getVisitorLog' does not exist or is not available in the module '\Piwik\Plugins\Actions\API'.

Is there another way to get to this? Or should I write a plugin for Piwik?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently [it is possible](http://forum.piwik.org/read.php?2,55831) through the Live plugin API:

http://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/reporting-api#Live

This works as desired:

http://example.com/piwik/index.php?module=API&method=Live.getLastVisitsDetails&format=JSON&idSite=1&period=day&date=2015-07-21&expanded=1&token_auth=XXXXX&filter_limit=100